# $.ajax get result from c# - page_load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

there are a lot of post about the subject but it does not help me!

I send data using jquery ajax to the same page and I handle it in the page_load.
is there a way to return data to the calling ajax?

my ajax in userLevel.aspx

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: location.href,
            dataType: 'text',
            data: "action=userData"
        }).done(function (result) {
            alert(result);
        });
```

my code_behind in userLevel.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=userLevel.aspx");
    }
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Form["action"] == "userData")
        {
           //bla bla bla...

           return "some data";
        }
    }
}
```

I know I cant return a value from a function that return void
but maybe I can use response.write?
It works when I send data to ashx, but when I try from code behind of the current page I get the whole html of the page.

Comment: You should use WebMethods :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=userLevel.aspx");
    return;
  }
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
    if (Request.Form["action"] == "userData")
    {
       Response.Clear();
       // if you want data to be specific , you should set content type
       // Set the ContentType
       //Response.ContentType = "application/json";
       Response.Write("some data");
       Response.End();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens with your solution is that I get the answer but I get the whole page html too, so I added Response.End(), and it works great.

Comment: I am trying to get data specific for user from DB(sqlserver), when page is loaded it has to be filled with user's data, i use jquery to fill the data and animate things on webpage, it has to happen only after the user is loged in. (if not, I can not get his data from the db)